# How to customize Pagination::slider view

Tags: pagination, laravel, laravel-4

I want to do some changes in Pagination::slider view, such as adding class and changing arrow style. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can change the view by adjusting the configuration option in `app/config/view.php`. Look for the `pagination` configuration option, by default it will be `pagination::slider`. This view namespace is [set in the view environment](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Pagination/Environment.php#L90).

Simply change this value to something like `pagination.slider` and then create the view in `views/pagination/slider.php`. You can then copy the [original slider view](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Pagination/views/slider.php) and adjust it to fit your needs.

Comment: Perfect answer Jason. I'm adding a very quick hint: if you plan on using the slider pagination view for the Twitter Bootstrap pagination component, Boostrap v3 requires the "pagination" class to be added to <ul> instead of <div> as per the default Laravel slider view.